# Why is my discord bot posting old memes? | Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a discord meme bot and its working but I have a small problem with it. It keeps sending the same set of old memes for some reason. How do I fix that?

```
def updateMemes(subreddit = "memes"): 
  global name
  global url 
  subreddit = reddit.subreddit("memes")
  allSubs = []

  top = subreddit.top(limit=100)

  for submission in top:
     allSubs.append(submission)

  randomSub = random.choice(allSubs)

  name = randomSub.title

  url = randomSub.url
```

Comment: It's hard to say without a [MRE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're explicitly requesting the top 100 posts of all time, which rarely change.

> top = subreddit.top(limit=100)

As you can see in the [PRAW docs](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.top), the default value for `time_filter` is `"all"`. If you want to get the top posts of today/this week/... instead, which will vary a lot more, then pass an argument for the `time_filter` parameter.

The accepted values, including examples, are in the docs page I linked.